# Sass media queries compiled css

Tags: html, css, sass, prepros

I've started using Sass and took my old css code and worked with it. For compiling I used prepros which has the option to compress CSS which saves some space.

The Problem I have is that when the SCSS code gets compiled into 1 line at the end the media query is empty

This is what my SCSS looks like, as an example

```
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
  body {
    background-color: red; }
}
```

and this is what gets compiled

```
body{background-color:blue;}@media all and (max-width: 900px){}
```

I'm not 100% sure with spaces but you get the point I think, it's in 1 line of code. 
When putting the thing into a new line it get's correctly highlighted in sublime text aswell.

Is there a way to still compress my css but get media queries to work?

Edit: I checked and the output looks exactly like this

```
@media all and (max-width: 900px){}
```

So it's not a bug with a missing space behind "and"

Edit2: Still not working, this is the exact code in my sublime text which doesn't work in the browser.

```
.overlay{-webkit-filter:blur(0);opacity:1;transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out}@media all and (max-width: 900px){}
```

Sublime doesn't think its right either https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAd5s.png

Where did my Code go? why is the compressed CSS missing the content of the media query

Comment: Works fine in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/corhovc7/).

Comment: If the compiled CSS validates, then the appropriate action is to file a bug report for Chrome.

Comment: It works with the classical ruby SASS (Compass) compiler so it has to be an issue with the Prepos App.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem too a few days ago, I don't think it was the case before the prepros update, but I have not found a way to make it work, unless I place the media query within the selector instead of outside.

So if you actually do it like:

```
body{
    @media all and (max-width: 900px){
        background-color: red;    
    }
}
```

Prepros shoudl compile it correctly. This is the way SASS intends the media queries to work, but since normal CSS is basically valid SCSS, I think prepros really should start supporting it the other way round again.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
background-color:red;
  @media all and (max-width:900px)
  {
    background-color:blue;
  }
 }
```